# Aligning images together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following code I inserted 5 images but I cannot put all of them in a single row and eliminate the spacing between them.

```
    <section class="images">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images1.jpg" alt="images1" max-width="400px" max-height="95px" width="auto" height="auto">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images2.jpg" alt="images2" max-width="230px" max-height="95px" width="auto" height="auto">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images3.jpg" alt="images3"  max-width="230px" max-height="95px" width="auto" height="auto">
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images4.jpg" alt="images4" max-width="230px" max-height="95px" width="auto" height="auto">
         </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images5.jpg" alt="images1">
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

How can I put the 5 images together and eliminate the space between the images?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap column divs come with padding. Eliminate them:

```
.row div {padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide the row into one wide image and four narrow images.

```
1 x 400px + 4 x 230px = 1320px
400px / 1320px = 10 / 33
230px / 1320px = 23 / 132
```

Oops, such parts are not suitable for the layout based on 12 columns. Because each of the columns has to

```
1320px / 12 = 110px
```

I suggest a little change the width of images:

```
440px = 4 x 110px
220px = 2 x 110px
```

The image 440 pixels wide will take 4 of 12 columns. The image 220 pixels wide will take 2 of 12 columns.

Remove the clearance between the columns:

```
.images {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.images .col-lg-2,
.images .col-lg-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Bootstrap determines `img-responsive` like so:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Therefore, we write

```
width="100%"
```

instead of

```
max-width="...px" max-height="95px" width="auto" height="auto"
```

Check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.images {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.images .col-lg-2,
.images .col-lg-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="images">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/440x95" alt="images1" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/220x95/ddd" alt="images2" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/220x95" alt="images3" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/220x95/ddd" alt="images4" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/220x95" alt="images5" width="100%">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify things!
Put everything in a `col-lg-12`, then add your images as elements of an inline-list. If you dont need columns for each image, an inline list should work just fine.
You then only have to adjust the margin/padding of your li img elements to determine how much space you want between them.

Much simpler, no?

Comment: I tried that but the display:inline-block does not make any difference and the images therefore remain one row instead of being aligned in a single block.

Comment: Read this: https://martinwolf.org/blog/2013/04/centered-fluid-width-navigation-with-floating-links-thanks-to-fit-content

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a full width is 100%.Therefore,if you need 5 images you simply divide 100 by 5 which will give 20%.
Check the html code:

```
    <footer class="images">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <img class="img-responsive" id="responsive" src="Dollarphotoclub_79081264-copy.jpg" alt="images1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <img class="img-responsive" id="responsive" src="beds.jpg" alt="images1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <img class="img-responsive" id="responsive" src="bed-cream.jpg" alt="images1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <img class="img-responsive" id="responsive" src="soaps.jpg" alt="images1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <img class="img-responsive" id="responsive" src="Dollarphotoclub_79081264-copy.jpg" alt="cake2">
                    </div>
              </div>
         </footer>
```

The css code will be as it follows:

```
.masterfooter .col-lg-2 {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}
```